# MariaDB query JSON result escapes a double quote in text column as \\"

Tags: mariadb, escaping, mysql-json, mariadb-10.5, json-arrayagg

I'm converting an SQL query to JSON using something like:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('field1', field1, ...)) FROM db.table
```

One of my columns of string type contain simple ASCII strings with double quotes (`"`) here and there.

My problem is that the double quotes are converted to `\\"`, which is invalid JSON.

How can I make sure that `\"` is generated instead?

Comment: I tested on MySQL 5.7 and got: `[{"field1": "\"myfield\""}]`. Cannot reproduce what you saw. What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @BillKarwin I have `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.8-MariaDB`.

Comment: Ah, you have the mysql client (v15.1) but the server is MariaDB, not MySQL. Their implementation of JSON is totally different from MySQL, so my test is not relevant. I don't use MariaDB, I consider it a completely different database product.

Comment: Can't reproduce that either on MariaDB 10.5.8: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=977a0c18e5c5b7e92e6babeefba8413e. Maybe your client is escaping the JSON string, not the database...

Comment: @GMB Thanks for checking. I run `mysql ... > MyFile.json` from the command line.